# jQuery run same code for two different events

Tags: jquery, dry

I have a form with a submit button.

I'd like to run the same piece of code for when the user clicks submit or they hit Enter.

This is the code so far:

```
    $('#submit').click(function(){

            //code

            return false;
    });
```

but i'd like to run the same "code" when the user hits the enter key whilst focused on the input with id = "artistName"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var myfunction = function(){
        //code
        return false;
}
$('#submit').click(myfunction);
$('#artistName').keyup(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        myfunction();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

put it into function

```
function function_name(){
   //code 
}
```

and trigger it like

```
$('#submit').click(function(){

        function_name();

        return false;
});
```

and trigger it whenever you want. for enter event, jut use .submit()

```
$("#form").submit(function(){
   function_name();
   return false;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try

```
$('#form_id').submit(function() {
    //your code
}
```

This way your code will execute when the form is submitted either by submit button or by hitting enter

Comment: This indeed answer the doubt of the user, however does not add any value to the real question "run same code for two different events"